# Can't apply CSS stylesheet to Wufoo form in Unbounce

Tags: css, wufoo

I have a Wufoo form inside an Unbounce landing page, and I'm trying to apply custom styling to the Wufoo form using a custom stylesheet. However, when I publish my changes, the stylesheet doesn't change the appearance of the form.

The form's HTML is generated by a javascript snippet inserted into the landing page, and the CSS stylesheet is nothing fancy (like, styling h2 tags and stuff, very beginner stuff).

Has anyone encountered this problem and/or knows how to solve it? Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the Javascript snippet that Wufoo uses -

```
var zzzzzz000000;
(function(d, t) {
  var s = d.createElement(t),
    options = {
      'userName': 'xxxxx',
      'formHash': 'yyyyy',
      'autoResize': true,
      'height': '483',
      'async': true,
      'host': 'wufoo.com',
      'header': 'show',
      'ssl': true
    };
  s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
  s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var rs = this.readyState;
    if (rs)
      if (rs != 'complete')
        if (rs != 'loaded') return;
    try {
      zzzzzz000000 = new WufooForm();
      zzzzzz000000.initialize(options);
      zzzzzz000000.display();
    } catch (e) {}
  };
  var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],
    par = scr.parentNode;
  par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');
```

Comment: Is the form inside an iframe? In case of iframe, you cannot style the form.

Comment: Nope, I've edited the original post to include the JS used by Wufoo to create the form.

Comment: I think the js is creating an iframe and dynamically inserting in the DOM

Comment: Checked in Chrome Dev Tools, and no iframe is being generated. Also found something published by Wufoo that claims CSS styling is possible (what I tried to do was pretty much what was published on the webpage): http://www.wufoo.com/guides/use-form-anatomy-custom-css/